# Is page table and GDT the same thing?

Tags: x86, operating-system, kernel, gdt

What're the differences between the "Page Table" concept and GDT?

Are the two the same?

Or GDT is just implementation to the Page Table concept?

Comment: They are different. GDT is for segmentation, page table is for paging. Consult the system programming guide or osdev [GDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT), [paging](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging)

Comment: @Jester aha, thank you.